# Windows 7 kernel raw socket send Error

Tags: windows, sockets, kernel, driver

Windows 7 SP1

I am writing a File System Driver trying to send data using a socket.

```
NTSTATUS NTAPI Connect(IN PWSK_SOCKET WskSocket, IN PSOCKADDR RemoteAddress)
{
    KEVENT CompletionEvent = { 0 };
    PIRP Irp = NULL;
    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
    PWSK_PROVIDER_CONNECTION_DISPATCH SocketDispatcher;

    if (g_SocketState != INITIALIZED || !WskSocket || !RemoteAddress)
        return STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;

    status = InitWskData(&Irp, &CompletionEvent);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        DbgPrint("Connect(): InitWskData() Failed Status 0x%08X\n", status);
        return status;
    }
    SocketDispatcher = (PWSK_PROVIDER_CONNECTION_DISPATCH)WskSocket->Dispatch;
    status = SocketDispatcher->WskConnect(WskSocket, RemoteAddress, 0, Irp); // <-- this line fails
    if (status == STATUS_PENDING)
    {
        KeWaitForSingleObject(&CompletionEvent, Executive, KernelMode, FALSE, NULL);
        status = Irp->IoStatus.Status;
    }
    IoFreeIrp(Irp);

    return status;
}
```

Creating a socket is successful, and `WSKStart()` is successful.

But connecting the socket is reporting an error.

```
status = SocketDispatcher->WskConnect(WskSocket, RemoteAddress, 0, Irp);
```

The status code is `0xC0000184`.

What is the problem?

Comment: 0xc0000184 means ["STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_STATE"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx)

Comment: The [`WskConnect()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff571125.aspx) says: "*A WSK application can call the WskConnect function **only on a connection-oriented socket that the application previously bound to a local transport address by calling the WskBind function**.*"  Are you calling [`WskBind()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff571121.aspx) before calling `WskConnect()`?

Comment: Does Client use bind Function?